# uwp parse or deserialize httpclient response

Tags: c#, json, uwp, httpclient, httpresponse

I writing app for UWP, i am using `HttpClient()` to communicate with server

Below code i have tried so far

```
    public async void POSTreq()
    {
        Uri requestUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com");
        string myParameters = "_action=LOGIN&username=xyz@abc.com&password=123456789";
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myParameters);
        var objClint = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage respon = await objClint.PostAsync(requestUri, new StringContent(myParameters, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        var responJsonText = await respon.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();            
        Debug.WriteLine(responJsonText);
    }
```

I don't know how to convert response data to Dictionary or list format

```
{"redirecturl":"https:\/\/www.example.com","status":"success","timestamp":1487906895,"community":"","communitystr":null,"currentworkspace":"w","schemarevision":null,"persona":null,"username":"xyz@abc.com","isadmin":"false","email1status":null}
```

Above string should be convert to

```
output['redirecturl']="https:/\/\www.example.com"

output['status']="success" etc..
```

Comment: As a comment just keep in mind to handle network exceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
var responJsonText = await respon.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Dictionary<string, string> output= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(responJsonText);
```

You can now access the properties' values like this: `output['redirecturl']`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you are accepted previously answer, but an another way is using dynamic variables, which can be useful when binding json objects.

Comment: Im ages away, but care to show your way so we can all learn,